# SQL command works only after manual change

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not a DB person but something weird is happening in Access:

I'm trying to run this SQL command: `UPDATE tbl_DirectorySet SET TempRootDir='D';`
on this table:

[image]

It doesn't do anything! I mean the field is empty as before.

If I manually set the field with some value like "aaaaa", then after I run the SQL command I can see that the command worked as expected.

Comment: You might have to commit your transaction.

Comment: Are there any rows to update? The screenshot would indicate there are none (the `*` on the left typically marks an unsaved row).

Comment: There are no rows in the table to update. Are you sure you don't want an insert?

Comment: @Richard if there is isn't rows, the command shouldn't create one aromatically?

Comment: `UPDATE` is used to make updations in existing data(rows). I think you need to use `INSERT`

Comment: As @w͏̢in̡͢g͘̕ed̨p̢͟a͞n͏͏t̡͜͝he̸r̴ notes: update only changes existing matching rows, it will never add new rows.

Comment: I need something like:
if (emty) then insert
else update

Comment: @RTExeption Manual thing is `INSERT`

Comment: @RTExeption `UPDATE` is a keyword that has the same meaning as in English language, "to give someone more or new information" or "a new form of something that existed at an earlier time". So why should this command add a new record? It doesn't make sense. You said you're not "a DB person" but you need to interact with Access, so give a read to what [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any record in a cell, the `UPDATE` command won't work. Use `INSERT` instead. That's why it works when you first introduce "aaaaa" and then you `UPDATE`.

**EDIT**: this link may make you understand better the principles behind the basic SQL commands: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete